# Yinwei or Yinvei? 因为

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

I hear some people say 因为 as “yinwei”, but also some say it sound like “yinvei”. I’m not sure why there is a difference in pronunciation.

Comment: You should notice that there's a thing called accent, which doesn't only occurs in foreigners.

Comment: To be clear, no /v/ exists in the pronunciation in Putonghua. However this is acceptable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

/v/ is not an initial found in [MSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese).

---

The initial /v/, though, is often found in Northern Mandarin and its branches. In fact, it can still be found, even, in distant branches like Sichuanese.

If you ever saw the [马蜂窝](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mq-pQpIwqIo) commercial that aired, ever single night, during the World Cup, you'd certainly notice that 唐僧's "为" is very /v/'d.

You can also refer to the paper [The geographic distribution rules and reasons of zero initial “w” pronounced as “v” in Mandarin](http://www.zndxsk.com.cn/upfile/soft/200861/200861183256465.pdf)  by Wang Fan. The abstract for the paper goes into some detail in English:

> **Abstract**:
>
> It  is  universal  to  pronounce  zero  initial  “w”  as  “v”  in Mandarin. Researches  show  that  38%  of  the  people with northern dialect do so with 10% in other dialect districts. When analyzing its features and reasons, we find that the dental fricative sound “v” is indeed a variant of the semi-vowel “w”. Its coming into being is affected by the variation of the  mouth  in  different  phonemes.  It  is  also  related  to  individual  pronunciation  habits  and  the  instability  of  the  pronunciation.  The  universal  “v”  pronunciation  in  northern  dialect  district  is  caused  by  the  stronger  movement  of  the mouth and the face in pronouncing than that in other dialect districts.

---

The 为 in 因为 should be pronounced `wei` if you're going for "standard" Mandarin. But, if you want to make yourself sound more Northernized you can also opt for the v.

Comment: The characters 维 and 为 both reads **wei** in Mandarin, but 维 reads as **vei** in our Xi'an dialect.

Answer (score 3):

There is no labiodental fricative [v], including in northerners' pronunciation. What you're hearing is a labiodental approximant [ʋ], which is sort of halfway between [w] and [v]. This is a variant pronunciation and phonemically equivalent to [w].

Because they are phonemically equivalent, both [w] and [ʋ] are represented by pinyin ⟨⁠w⁠⟩, rather than ⟨⁠v⁠⟩ or anything else.

The paper cited by the accepted answer looks pretty questionable to me, given that it doesn't make any distinction between labiodental fricative and labiodental approximant. In addition, the translation of 普遍 as "universal" in the abstract is wrong, because pronunciation of [w] with some dentalization is *not* universal, but rather a variant pronunciation that (by the paper's own conclusions) is in the minority.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mandarin, *yinwei*, but you may pronounce as *yinvei*, it is just another variant of pronunciation of the word.

Comment: Hokkien, Cantonese, Hakka all say it with a "W"

Comment: @WayneCheah, oh, man, Cantonese is not mandarin.

Answer (score -1):

因为 is always pronounced as /Yīn wèi/

/yin vei/ sounds like a foreigner's mispronunciation of the words

there is no /vei/ sound in Mandarin pinyin (I searched all 4 tones)

Comment: It really _doesn't_ sound like a "foreigner's mispronunciation"--it sounds like a Northerner's mispronunciation! I've had professors at 复旦 who talk this way (who I presume were from the north).

Comment: It's very common among speakers in the north who otherwise have perfectly standard Mandarin, including teachers.